# PHP OOP - Array of classes within a class

Tags: php, oop

I was wondering how you can define an array of objects within another object.

For example, let's say I have a class called "User", and another class called "Address".

A user can list an unlimited number of addresses. How do I do this?

My guess is that I need to declare an array of "Address" objects within the "User" class, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a class, with a property that is an array, then add to the array:

```
<?php

class User
{
    private $addresses = [];

    public function addAddress(Address $address)
    {
        $this->addresses[] = $address;
    }

    public function getAddresses()
    {
        return $this->addresses;
    }
}

class Address
{
    private $street;

    public function __construct($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;
        // ... etc
    }
}

$user = new User();
$user->addAddress(new Address("Foo"));
$user->addAddress(new Address("Bar"));

var_dump($user->getAddresses());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class User {
    private $address;

    public function addAddress($street) {
        $this->address[] = new Address($street);
    }

    public function getAddress($i) {
        return $this->address[$i]->street;
    }
}

class Address {
    public $street;

    public function __construct($s) {
        $this->street = $s;
    }
}

$u = new User;
$u->addAddress('abc');
$u->addAddress('def');
$u->addAddress('zzz');

echo $u->getAddress(2);
```

Comment: You're doing some nasty tight coupling here. You should not be making the instance of the address object within the user object. Think about how you could test that? This would make it very difficult.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare it like this:

```
$user = new stdClass; // declare the user object
$user->firstName = "John"; // add firstName property
$user->lastName = "Doe"; // add lastName property
$user->addresses = array(); // add addresses property as an array

//declare a couple of dummy address objects
$address1 = new stdClass;
$adresss1->street = "Elm Street";

$address2 = new stdClass;
$adresss2->street = "Arlington Road";

//Add the generated address objects into the addresses array of the user
$user->adresses[] = $address1;
$user->adresses[] = $address2;
```

Let me know if this helps. Cheers!

Comment: `stdClass` doesn't really seem like an actual solution in this case. It's not a "User" and "Address" object, they're both just instances of stdClass, which means you're not benefiting from most things you use OOP for.

Comment: You are completely right. I did not want to over confuse him with classes and setters and getters and what not. Just plane simple to understand the basic nesting principles. Cheers!